# What does "for about a month" in "for about a month of European festivals" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning

> You're all going on tour for about a month of European festivals this summer.

What does "for about a month" mean in this sentence? That they're going on tour in a month or that this tour will take a month?

Thanks. :)

Comment: As you wrote, if it meant "they're going on tour in a month", you would use "in (about) a month".

Answer (score 1):

> for about a month

the duration of the tour.

Contrast with these that tell us when the tour starts

> ... in about a month

or

> in a month's time you're all going ...